# Could not start Hive Web Interface

Tags: hadoop, hive

**My HIVE_HOME = /home/hduser/bin/hive-0.11.0-bin/**

When I try to run

```
#hive --service hwi
```

I get this error:

INFO hwi.HWIServer: HWI is starting up

FATAL hwi.HWIServer: HWI WAR file not found at /home/hduser/bin/hive-0.11.0-bin/home/hduser/bin/hive-0.11.0-bin/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war**

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the war is in the directory hive is pointing to?

Comment: The jar is there in ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war. In my ${HIVE_HOME}/conf/hive-default.xml I have <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name><value>/lib/hive_hwi.war</value>. Still why it is finding the WAR specified in error?

Comment: When you are saying the jar is in `${HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war`, and assuming `HIVE_HOME=/home/hduser/bin/hive-0.11.0-bin/` as you have already mentioned, doesn't it mean you have the war in `/home/hduser/bin/hive-0.11.0-bin/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war`?

Comment: @JtheRocker: Yes you are correct then why it is looking at /home/hduser/bin/hive-0.11.0-bin/home/hduser/bin/hive-0.11.0-bin/lib/hive-hwi-0.11.0.war?

Comment: [enter link description here][1]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798034/could-not-start-hive-web-interface
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798034/could-not-start-hive-web-interface
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798034/could-not-start-hive-web-interface

Answer (score 0):

Please try with adding the following instead --

```
<property>
  <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
  <value>${HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive_hwi.war</value>
  <description>This is the WAR file with the jsp content for Hive Web Interface</description>
</property>
```

You have to make sure `${HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive_hwi.war` is accessible.

To confirm that you can do a `ls -l ${HIVE_HOME}/lib/hive_hwi.war` from the terminal and see if you can access the war file.

Please [check this link for reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveWebInterface) (you might already know this) but sharing with your anyways.

Comment: No, it did'nt fix the problem but if I change my hive-default.xml to hive-site.xml it works. Thanks for helping @JtheRocker.

Comment: @techvineet: Glad that your found the issue. I just tried to help. Yeah, you definitely need hive-site.xml to override hive-default.xml. I though you already knew about that, so didn't go till there.